# What is the best way to check the running status of a Timer?

Tags: java, timer

Desired Output: I would like to check for the running condition of the timer and run some code based on that status.

I have the following code...

```
      if (spin2 == spin3 && timer1.stop()==true)
  {

      lblMessage.setText("Congratulations. You matched 2 symbols");
      credit = credit + 50;
      lblCredit2.setText(credit + " ");
      lblCredit2.setForeground(new Color(11,212,0));
      timer1.stop();
      timer2.stop();
      timer3.stop();

  }
```

However, timer1.stop() == true does not work. I need an alternative...

**An Idea:**

Is changing the value of a boolean when I call start() or stop() the best way to approach the running condition of a timer? or Is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Instead of

```
timer1.stop()==true //Which isnt even valid because timer.stop doesnt return a boolean
```

Use

```
timer1.isRunning(); //It returns a boolean (true or false) if the timer is running or not.
```

Returns True when timer is Running.

Returns False when timer is not Running.

---

This would have been a simple fix if you refered to the API.

**Heres the Link:**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#isRunning()

Comment: @MichaelG Hope This Helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! got it working and is running perfectly!